# Confused by Value to String node

Tags: node-editor, geometry

Why do I get a red line from the Separate XYZ node to the Value to String node?

[image]

I'm trying to break the vector down into it's component parts, and examine the X component. At least, that's what I'm trying to do. I'm obviously doing something very, very stupid, but  quite what eludes me.

Comment: broken lines are more than 1 value. so you can't connect multiple values to a slot that accepts only 1 value.

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what's puzzling me. I think I'm taking a vector, and breaking it down into it's component X, Y, and Z parts. But it's not allowing me to peek at what X is. When I siphon the X value off and use it in the Greater Than test, it works - I can vary what gets extruded based on the X value. I just can't feed it to the Value to String node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A diamond shaped socket outputs a [Field](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/fields.html), which is basically a function that operates on an input.

The used *Position* node outputs a field which represents the positions of every element requested by the next node.

That mean it does not output a single value, like $3$ or $4.7$ because in the illustrated case it is producing an array of values for the positions of the vertex in the *Grid* node.

The *Value to String* node on the other hand can only receive a single value to convert to a single string.

Comment: Ah, OK, I see. I need to review my mental map of how it works under the hood. Many thanks.